# Migrating DNN (DotNetNuke) to Godaddy Plesk

Tags: dotnetnuke

I was a given a task that I have never done before. I was asked to move a DNN website to Godaddy Plesk.

What I've done so far are...
 1. Move the files to httpdocs folder. 
 2. Created a database

Now, I'm not sure what to do next, I have the database in .mdf file extension but there is no option in Plesk that will allow to upload the database. I've read some tutorials and some mentioned that there suppose to have an "Import Dump" option in Plesk control panel but in my case, there is none.

I hope someone could lead to me the right path. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't upload .mdf file, you need to upload full .bak file. Please convert it to .bak file first. You can run this script to convert it:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [NameOfDatabase] TO  DISK = N'D:\path\filename.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'NameOfDatabase-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

Then, you can test to import it. If there is issue, you can contact their support team. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In your position, I would call GoDaddy's support team and ask them how to do it.

---

This isn't a real answer, but is advice that might be worth more than an answer.

But, if I really was in your position, I'd try to convince the powers that be to move the site to a hosting situation where DNN is known and supported. There are many such hosting companies.  Three who come to mind are Managed.com (PowerDNN), DNN4Less, and Applied Innovations.

You can also host DNN in Azure.  I haven't done that, but there are people who can help you do that, too.  Try Iowa Computer Gurus.

Note:  Besides the names of companies mentioned above, there are many, many more .... you just have to look for them.  And, I know almost nothing about hosting companies outside of the US.